# Darlington Pair TIP41C at op amp output not amplifying current

Tags: linear-regulator, darlington

I am trying to make a variable voltage regulator with the TL081CP op amp. When I add a single TIP41C transistor the max current I can get at the 20 ohm 20 W load is about 625 mA.

But when I want to amplify the current with a Darlington pair combination, the max current only becomes 610 mA. Why won't it amplify?

The test voltage represents the unregulated voltage I am getting at the output which is about 23 V with very small ripple. The slider at the inverting input is at its maximum. I've tried everything but the current won't amplify further.

The op-amp is also continuously sinking current to keep track of the output voltage. Could this be the reason? I've added arrows to indicate the direction of current flow. Voltage at non inverting input is 5.005 V and at inverting input 4.883 V.

Can it be fixed and what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: With a 5.6V zener and R1/X1 forming a voltage divider from there to the non-inverting input, how do you get 5V there? 5.6V with a 14.8k/100k divider (X1 at its maximum) should put 4.88V on the non-inverting input.

Comment: Have you looked at the output on an oscilloscope to see if it's oscillating?

Comment: Sinking? Conventional current follows the semiconductor arrows.

Comment: 625mA into 20 ohms is 12.5V, plus two Vbe's is about 13.9V.  TL082 V_OH min is lower than that (I think, offhand). You're lucky to be getting what you are, I think? Why not reduce RLOAD1? Also, what are the pots set at?

Comment: Which current do you want to amplify? Is current amplification the task of the circuit?

Comment: VSS has wrong polarity.

Comment: Its a 14.8k resistor in series with a 100kohm potentiometer. The voltage across the zener is 5.74 V and is in breakdown, I wanted a 5V reference at the upper terminal of the potentiometer. There is 50uA that runs through the14.8k resistor giving a voltage drop of 0.74 V. So 5.74-0.74 = 5V. I don't have an oscilloscope I can only simulate.

Comment: I can't get any example on the web that shows a similar example of an op amp sourcing current to the base of the NPN to compensate for the error voltage..
I thought it was supposed to source current. For example when the slider at potentiometer X1 is 50/50 the non inverting input says 2.5 V which is correct.
The same at the inverting input. But for some reason the op-amp needs to sink current to achieve this. LTSpice says its sucking 2.4 mA from the NPN base at this point. Current from Vtest is 309 mA and current is 312 mA at the emitter. (Single NPN)

Comment: @Jens - V4 is set to -15V (not +15V), so Vss is the correct polarity since the '+' side of V4 is negative.

Comment: @ChristopherOtniel - Hi, You have now asked [a follow-up question on the same subject](/q/644283). Is *this* question still needed? If so, please edit *both* questions, add a link to the other one, and in each question explain how they are different and what help is still needed in each one. || Please be careful not to have multiple overlapping questions open at the same time, as it can annoy people if they spend time on a question which is actually obsolete, due to an overlapping question that they didn't know about. Thanks.

Comment: @brhans Thank you, I need new glasses

Comment: @SamGibson Sorry its my first time using stack exchange

Comment: @ChristopherOtniel - Thanks for your reply. Stack Exchange is different from typical internet forums and has its own rules & etiquette. Please read the [tour] & [help] to see the main site rules. || So, back to your questions. What is going on? You have 2 overlapping questions. Which one(s) do you still need help with? Has either question been answered (either in an actual answer or a comment)? Has the [later question](/q/644283) made [*this* earlier question](/q/644254) now obsolete? If you explain what's going on, then I'll try to advise you, while avoiding other people wasting time. Thanks.